# MFMailComposeViewController app crash in ipad

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, xcode4, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have a problem in MFMailComposeViewController.

if no one login in mail and i try to open this view, app crashes 
how to solve this?

if i login frommail in ipad and after that i try to load this its working fine.

Thanks,

Shyam Parmar

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know the MFMailComposer requires a mail account in-order to send mail so if an account is not set up it will cause problems. you can check if the mfmailcomposer can send mail through its method `[MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail];`